# VARCHAR vs TEXT performance when data fits on row

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

```
mysql> desc temp1;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| value | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> desc temp2;
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| value | text | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**255 - 'a' characters in each row(In both tables)**

```
mysql> select * from temp1 limit 1;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select * from temp2 limit 1;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Query table 1:**

```
select count(*) from temp1 where value like '%a';
```

**Query table 2:**

```
select count(*) from temp2 where value like '%a';
```

**Stats:**

```
No of records---temp1(varchar)---temp2(text)


2097152---------6.08(sec)--------6.91(sec)          
4194304---------12.42(sec)-------13.66(sec)
8388608---------25.08(sec)-------28.03(sec)
16777216--------52.82(sec)-------56.88(sec)
33554432--------1(min)50.17(sec)-1(min)59.36(sec)
```

**My question:** How can the difference in execution speed be explained?

The rows contents are same in both tables.

As I understood `VarChar` and `Text` columns keep contents offPage only when it exceeds row size. So both tables contents will be inline data for my `page size(16kb)`. Then what was the reason for this query execution time difference.

> Note: Both table column is not indexed

```
Row Format - DYNAMIC

Collation - UTF8mb3

Character set - utf8_general_ci

Storage engine -  innodb

Mysql - 5.7
```

Reference link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48301727/5431418

***Update:***
Same flow now I tried with 5000 characters ('a') in both tables the result difference is high.

```
2097152---------1(min)53.63(sec)--------2(min)4.66(sec)
```

***Update 2:***
Same flow now I tried with 2 characters ('a') in both tables still there is  a performance difference

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58065891/varchar-vs-text-performance-when-data-fits-on-row?noredirect=1#comment102928274_58065891

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you ask this question somewhere else?

Didn't the answer come back that `TEXT` fields are preallocated at full size?  That is the "allocation" mechanism for `SELECT` has a bias toward `VARCHAR`.